# Child row not getting deleted using php code but working on database level

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-key-relationship, cascade

I have created two tables with following details:

table: event

[image]

table: notification

[image]

In this, event table is parent table and notification table in child table.

I have set foreign key constaint on following:

```
 notification table -> event_id  -> foreign key reference (event->id)
```

When I am deleting record from event table in database, notification records are also getting deleted.

But when i am performing delete operation on event table through php code, i am getting following error:

```
    Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
    (`db_lgo_2014`.`notification`, CONSTRAINT `notification_ibfk_1` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) 
    REFERENCES `event` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

I am not getting why this is happening?

please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: probably the phpmyadmin software handles the deletion so it does not break the constraint; if possible a transaction should do it, since you "break" the constraint only during transation, but its ok again at commit time (if I remeber DB classes correctly)

Comment: you can't break an FK relationship even inside a transaction. a child record can never be "orphaned". @kalpana: how is your FK defined? do you have an `on delete cascade`? If not, then you'd have to manually delete all child records BEFORE you delete the parent records.

Comment: @MarcB: Yes i have set on delete and on update cascade and its working when i am delete records from mysql database->event table but when i am doing same from php code, i am getting error.

Comment: And parent record is getting deleted from php code also but i am getting error while deleting child records using cascade